# EF Code First: Fluent API Configuration - How to configure properties of subclasses in TPH?

Tags: entity-framework

If I have a base class and two derived classes in a TPH configuration, how to configure the scalar properties of the derived classes (e.g. length of string) in fluent API?

Example:
    public enum PersonType { Employee, Manager }

```
public abstract class Person 
{ 
    public string FirstName {get; set;} 
    public string LastName {get; set;} 
} 

public class Employee : Person 
{ 
    public string Designation {get; set;} 
} 

public class Manager : Person 
{ 
    public string Division {get; set;} 
} 

//fluent api config 
internal class PersonConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{ 
    public PersonConfig() 
    { 
        Property(p => p.FirstName) .HasMaxLength(250); 
        Property(p => p.LastName) .HasMaxLength(250); 
        Map<Employee>(e => e.Requires(x => x.PersonType).HasValue()); 
        **//how to configure Designation ?** 
        Map<Manager>(m => m.Requires(y => y.PersonType).HasValue()); 
        **//how to configure Division ?** 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configure derived entities the same way you configure regular entities - by using separate fluent configuration, e.g.

```
internal class EmployeeConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{ 
    public EmployeeConfig() 
    { 
        Property(e => e.Designation).HasMaxLength(250);
        // ... 
    } 
}

internal class ManagerConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Manager>
{ 
    public ManagerConfig() 
    { 
        Property(m => m.Division).HasMaxLength(250);
        // ... 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivan Stoev! Thanks for the quick response. Your suggestion seems to be perfect. Can you please confirm if creating separate type configurations for derived classes wouldn't create tables for those. I'm expecting TPH behaviour, i.e. only one table with a discriminator field for derived classes. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely. It will create separate tables **only** if you explicitly request that via `ToTable`, which is used to set up TPT.